# Can I push remotes to a remote?

Tags: git

I know that with push-to-empty and clone-mirror you can push lots of things to new repositories, not only your commits. For example, you can get remote branches to be copied. But is there any way to transfer across the remotes themselves?

Especially with clone-mirror, I thought intuitively it was supposed to be a mirror of everything in the other repository. So I was surprised that this does not seem to include the remotes.

In the below example I took a repo ("repo1") with two remotes "dest" and "blah", and pushed it to a new bare repository "repo2" (push-to-empty). I also took the same "repo1" and clone-mirrored it to "repo3". In the case of "repo2", none of the remotes or remote refs were pushed. In the case of "repo3", the remote ref for the "dest" remote was copied (NB: to be fair, this branch did not exist at the time I pushed to "repo2" as it tracks the same), but there was no trace of the other remote ("blah").

```
C:\test-remote>mkdir repo1bare

C:\test-remote>cd repo1bare

C:\test-remote\repo1bare>git init --bare
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/test-remote/repo1bare/

C:\test-remote\repo1bare>git ls-remote .

C:\test-remote\repo1bare>cd ..

C:\test-remote>git clone .\repo1bare .\repo1wd
Cloning into '.\repo1wd'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
done.

C:\test-remote>cd repo1wd

C:\test-remote\repo1wd>git remote -v
origin  C:/test-remote/.\repo1bare (fetch)
origin  C:/test-remote/.\repo1bare (push)

C:\test-remote\repo1wd>copy con dummy.txt
^Z
        1 file(s) copied.

C:\test-remote\repo1wd>git add dummy.txt

C:\test-remote\repo1wd>git commit -m "dummy"
[master (root-commit) bf946c1] dummy
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 dummy.txt

C:\test-remote\repo1wd>git push -u origin master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 211 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To C:/test-remote/.\repo1bare
 * [new branch]      master -> master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.

C:\test-remote\repo1wd>cd ..\repo1bare

C:\test-remote\repo1bare>git ls-remote .
bf946c1f3d14b287b2973fdfcca7379415dbc486        HEAD
bf946c1f3d14b287b2973fdfcca7379415dbc486        refs/heads/master

C:\test-remote\repo1bare>git remote -v

C:\test-remote\repo1bare>git remote add blah http://blah.com/repo1

C:\test-remote\repo1bare>git remote -v
blah    http://blah.com/repo1 (fetch)
blah    http://blah.com/repo1 (push)

C:\test-remote\repo1bare>cd ..

C:\test-remote>mkdir repo2bare

C:\test-remote\repo1bare>cd repo2bare

C:\test-remote\repo2bare>git init --bare
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/test-remote/repo2bare/

C:\test-remote\repo2bare>cd ..\repo1bare

C:\test-remote\repo1bare>git remote add dest C:\test-remote\repo2bare

C:\test-remote\repo1bare>git remote -v
blah    http://blah.com/repo1 (fetch)
blah    http://blah.com/repo1 (push)
dest    C:\test-remote\repo2bare (fetch)
dest    C:\test-remote\repo2bare (push)

C:\test-remote\repo1bare>git push --all dest
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 211 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To C:\test-remote\repo2bare
 * [new branch]      master -> master

C:\test-remote\repo1bare>cd ..\repo2bare

C:\test-remote\repo2bare>git remote -v

C:\test-remote\repo2bare>git ls-remote .
bf946c1f3d14b287b2973fdfcca7379415dbc486        HEAD
bf946c1f3d14b287b2973fdfcca7379415dbc486        refs/heads/master

C:\test-remote\repo2bare>cd ..

C:\test-remote>git clone .\repo1bare --mirror .\repo3bare
Cloning into bare repository '.\repo3bare'...
done.

C:\test-remote>cd repo3bare

C:\test-remote\repo3bare>git remote -v
origin  C:/test-remote/.\repo1bare (fetch)
origin  C:/test-remote/.\repo1bare (push)

C:\test-remote\repo3bare>git ls-remote .
bf946c1f3d14b287b2973fdfcca7379415dbc486        HEAD
bf946c1f3d14b287b2973fdfcca7379415dbc486        refs/heads/master
bf946c1f3d14b287b2973fdfcca7379415dbc486        refs/remotes/dest/master

C:\test-remote\repo3bare>
```

Comment: You can only push commits and references between repositories.  You cannot push configuration information like a list of remotes, or hook scripts, or other repository metadata.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise it was configuration. So any remotes will appear in `git config --list`, right? If I can identify them, can I just copy and paste them into another repository's config somehow? Is there any way to retrieve only those configuration items related to remotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a list of `git` remotes associated with your local repository like this:

```
git config --get-regexp '^remote\.'
```

Which will produce something like:

```
remote.origin.url git@github.com:larsks/oschecks.git
remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

You could use these to feed a script on the other end that would feed this into `git config` (and then probably `git remote update` to load the content of the remote repositories).